# Ajax request in progress jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to check if there's ajax request in progress?
Something like:

```
if ( $.ajax.inProgress ){ do this; } else { do that; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should basically set a variable on top of script set to `false` and on ajax initiate set it to `true` and in the `success` handler set it to `false` again as **[described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008507/jquery-ajax-request-wait-for-latest-request-to-finish)**.

Comment: Sometimes best solutions are the simplest ones :) Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I am testing a webpage and I would like to know how will I get to know when the Ajax request is complete using a Java Script(i.e I have no control of the web page, I can just inject a Java script)?

Comment: For simple pages, this is fine, but I have to say that an approach that demands that every developer on a project always remember to set a variable every time they do an ajax request AND update it both on failure and success (or on complete/finally) is not a good approach for any complicated project.

Comment: This approach fails as soon as multiple requests overlap. The first completing request will (incorrectly) set the variable to false. It's better to use $(document).ajaxStart() and $(document).ajaxStop(), see the answer of Gutzofter below for details.

Answer (score 13):

yes there is

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: 'url',
     data: {
              email: $email.val()
     },
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(data)
     {
        if(data == '1')
        {
            $response.attr('style', '')
                     .attr('style', "color:red;")
                     .html('Email already registered please enter a different email.');
        }
        else
        {
            $response.attr('style', '')
                     .attr('style', "color:green;")
                     .html('Available');
        }
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
                $email.addClass('show_loading_in_right')
     },
     complete: function(){
                $email.removeClass('show_loading_in_right')
     }
});
```

the **beforeSend** will do the process you need to do when the ajax request has just started and **complete** will be called when the ajax request is complete.

**[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's question. He doesn't want to know how to fire handlers prior to sending the request or after the request completes, he wants to fire certain events when a request is *ongoing*...

Answer (score 8):

To abort ajax request,
Use

```
if($.active > 0){ 
ajx.abort();//where ajx is ajax variable
}
```

To continue running ajax request,
Use

```
if($.active > 0){ 
return;

}
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation regarding $.active. Can you show some example for applying this function?

Comment: @Ganesh, Have a look at these post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function.

Answer (score 4):

You might like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var working = false;
    $("#contentLoading").ajaxSend(function(r, s) {
        $(this).show();
        $("#ready").hide();
        working = true;
    });

    $("#contentLoading").ajaxStop(function(r, s) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#ready").show();
        working = false;
    });

    $('#form').submit(function() {
        if (working) return;
        $.post('/some/url', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in full control of the javascript code you could increment a variable whenever you start an ajax request and decrement it when the request completes (with success, failure or timeout). This way you always know if there is a request in progress.