# jQuery.active function

Tags: jquery

I was trying to find some more information on the following jQuery function:

```
jQuery.active
```

It is described to test the number of active connections to a server and will evaluate true when the number of connections is zero.

I could not find any information about this function on the jQuery site and was wondering if anyone knew where I could.

Comment: Is it now or was it ever a function?

Comment: This takes me back lol

Comment: This question seems to be the canonical resource so it'd be nice to get some clarification and editorial updates for this decade about it since it's still available in 3.6.0.  I don't think it was ever a function.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This is a variable jQuery uses internally, but had no reason to hide, so it's there to use.  Just a heads up, [it becomes `jquery.ajax.active` next release](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L574).  There's no documentation because it's *exposed* but not in the official API, lots of things are like this actually, like [`jQuery.cache`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/data.js#L4) (where all of [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) goes).

I'm guessing here by *actual* usage in the library, it seems to be there exclusively to support [`$.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`$.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) (which I'll explain further), but they only care if it's 0 or not when a request starts or stops.  But, since there's no reason to hide it, it's exposed to you can see the actual number of **simultaneous** AJAX requests currently going on.

---

When jQuery starts an AJAX request, [this happens](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L282):

```
if ( s.global && ! jQuery.active++ ) {
  jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStart" );
}
```

This is what causes the [`$.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) event to fire, the number of connections just went from 0 to 1 (`jQuery.active++` isn't 0 after this one, and `!0 == true`), this means the first of the current **simultaneous** requests started.  The same thing happens at the other end.  When an AJAX request stops (because of [a `beforeSend` abort via `return false`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L379) or an [ajax call `complete` function runs](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L518)):

```
if ( s.global && ! --jQuery.active ) {
  jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );
}
```

This is what causes the [`$.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event to fire, the number of requests went down to 0, meaning the last **simultaneous** AJAX call finished.  The [other global AJAX handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) fire in there along the way as well.

Comment: I saw it described in a book jQuery Novice to Ninja (2010)

Comment: @Nick : As per your explanation of .ajaxStop will be executed after every ajax call completed. But, it will be called if all ajax calls were completed. Can you please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KishoreRelangi I tried to be very explicit with the `0 to 1` and `number of requests went down to 0` bits above that is is global and **not** every request.  It's when the first one starts and the last active one finishes (which of course may be out of order).

Comment: This is now called `$.active`, btw.

Comment: @RyanBigg isn't `$` simply an alias for `jQuery`, so both are still true?

Comment: @ArxPoetica only if you're running `jQuery` without `noConflict`.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone trying to use jQuery.active with JSONP requests (like I was) you'll need enable it with this:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.global = true;
});
```

Keep in mind that you'll need a timeout on your JSONP request to catch failures.