# Waiting for jQuery AJAX response(s)

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a page that, using jQuery .ajax that is called 100 times (async: true), the problem is that, when they they are all being loaded, I need the system to wait for ALL 100 calls to return before continuing. How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Update:

These calls are made in a for() loop (there's 100 of them :))

Comment: Are these seperate ajax() calls or one where you change the request URL?

Comment: I think the very same solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239333/preventing-submit-until-ajaxes-are-done could work for you.

Comment: Matthew Riches: Several.

Niklas: Thanks :) I'll look into that!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The nice way to do this is with [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).  You can use this as follows:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({/*settings*/}),
    $.ajax({/*settings*/}),
    $.ajax({/*settings*/}),
    $.ajax({/*settings*/}),
).then(function() {
    // when all AJAX requests are complete
});
```

Alternatively, if you have all the AJAX calls in an array, you could use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply):

```
$.when.apply($, ajaxReqs);
```

Note that this requires at least jQuery 1.5.

---

To add the AJAX requests to an array, do something like this:

```
var ajaxReqs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    ajaxReqs.push($.ajax({
        /* AJAX settings */
    });
}
$.when.apply($, ajaxReqs).then(function() {
    // all requests are complete
});
```

Comment: Aaargh... just when you think you're pwned jQuery, there's something new.

Comment: I have all the Ajax calls in a for loop, how do I 'add' them to an array then? :)

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be the solution I'm using :)

Comment: Can I just ask, my '100' loop is inside another, bigger loop, will this pause the bigger loop when waiting for the Ajax or will it continue? :)

Comment: @Eax It's asynchronous, so the outer loop will continue.

Comment: How would I go about pausing it then?

Comment: Restructure your code so that the code that needs to be delayed goes in the `then` callback. Embrace asynchronous programming!

Comment: fantastic answer. top marks

Answer (score 4):

This kind of issue crops up everywhere in database SQL design - and although its not precisely the same - the issue is exactly the thing that'll get you: network communications.

You need to watch out for it because it'll come back to bite you if you don't do it correctly - ie users will get severely annoyed HAVING to wait. I can't emphasize this enough.

Here's the scenario:
You want to transfer many small snippets of information from your server upon request. 
Each request depends on a number of factors operating efficiently. All of which are OUT OF YOUR CONTROL:

```
Wide area Network reposnse time (anywhere in the world right?)
Locak area Network reposnse time (anywhere in the building)
WebServer Load
WebServer Response time
Database response time
Backend Script run time
Javascript run time to process the result
The fact that the browsers are generally limited to 6-8 parallel AJAX requests at once (I think - someone correct me on the exact number)
```

Multiply that by request (erm...in your case x 100)

Get the picture?

It might work blissfully well in test on a local machine. You might even be running your own db and webserver on the exact same machine... but try that in the wild and before long you'll hit unreliability as an issue.

Listen, the simplist thing to do is wrap up ALL your parameters into ONE JS array and send that in ONE POST request. Then on the server do all your database selects and roll up the responses into ONE JSON/XML reponse.

At that point you are only ever waiting for ONE AJAX response. You can find all your data in the JSON/XML result.

Given that you are working with 100 requests you would probably be able to actually measure the time saving with a stopwatch!

Take it from me - do as few network requests as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for an extremely elaborate answer :)

However, (there's always one of these, isn't there?), what I'm AJAX'ing isn't actually a database, but instead, a page that scrapes a specific website for info.
So I can't really make all those 100 requests at a time, or rather, I can, but that takes HOURS (I did the stopwatch test;) ) Whereas, when running with jQuery+Ajax it takes minutes :)

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to get a web page seerved in *hours*? I've done the same thing using CURL to acquire metadata from pages before. It can only take the time it takes to serve the page, so you must have been doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Deferred object api](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). As long as $.ajax returns deferred object you can try the following code to use loop:

```
var ajaxes = [];
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  ajaxes[i] = $.ajax({/*data*/});
}

$.when.apply( ajaxes )
   .then(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire once all ajax requests have completed!' );
   })
   .fail(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
   });
```

P.S. There is a great article regarding using deferred objects by Eric Hynds [Using Deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/)

Comment: I updated the main question, can I still use your way if I'm making all the Ajax calls in a for loop?

Comment: This won't work. If you pass anything other than a Deferred object to `$.when` (including an array containing deferred objects), it will return immediately. You need to use `$.when.apply` as in my answer to get around this.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

100 Ajax calls? Seems a very odd requirement and what you're trying to achieve could quite possibly be achieved using another method:

```
var i = 0;

function myCallback() {
    alert('Completed 100 times');
}

function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'blah.php',
        data: 'hello=world',
        success: function(response) {
            i++;
        },
        complete: function() {
            if(i < 100) {
                doAjax();
            } else {
                myCallback();
            }
        }
    });
}

doAjax(); // start
```

Comment: I Know it's quite odd :)
I should probably add that each call is different, and that I need all the return data..

Comment: In which way is each call different? Different end URLs? Different data? It's easy enough to manipulate my answer to allow that and store the returned data in another variable, which is sent to the callback function.

Comment: Different data :)
But I guess it adds up being the same thing, just need to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JS guy but I would create a global variable, this would be the counter, and define a timed function to check this global var periodically if it reached 100 or not.

EDIT: setTimeout()

Comment: What do you mean by a timed function? :)

Comment: forget it, as I see you'll get better solutions