# Get info on active ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know that i can make use of `$.active` to get the current amount of active ajax requests. But is there any way to get more detailed data of each call? Like the `data` from the call for example. Thanks

Comment: Related: [jQuery.active function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3148225)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an app like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  It allows you to see source of those requests.  There is a handy firefox plugin too.