# Include module in all MiniTest tests like in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, minitest

In RSpec I could create helper modules in `/spec/support/...`

```
module MyHelpers
  def help1
    puts "hi"
  end
end
```

and include it in every spec like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(MyHelpers)
end
```

and use it in my tests like this:

```
describe User do
  it "does something" do
    help1
  end
end
```

How can I include a module into all MiniTest tests without repeating myself in every test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

minitest does not *provide* a way to `include` or `extend` a module into every test class in the same way RSpec does.

Your best bet is going to be to re-open the test case class (differs, depending on the minitest version you're using) and `include` whatever modules you want there. You probably want to do this in either your `test_helper` or in a dedicated file that lets everyone else know you're monkey-patching minitest. Here are some examples:

For minitest ~> 4 (what you get with the Ruby Standard Library)

```
module MiniTest
  class Unit
    class TestCase
      include MyHelpers
    end
  end
end
```

For minitest 5+

```
module Minitest
  class Test
    include MyHelperz
  end
end
```

You can then use the included methods in your test:

```
class MyTest < Minitest::Test # or MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_something
    help1
    # ...snip...
  end
end
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thx for your answer. You've suggested moneky patching in a separate file, but  what's wrong with just doing the following `class FiftySevenSqlExercise < Minitest::Test; include MyHelperz; # all that jazz   ; end; `?

Answer (score 20):

From the Minitest README:

```
=== How to share code across test classes?

Use a module. That's exactly what they're for:

module UsefulStuff
  def useful_method
    # ...
  end
end

describe Blah do
  include UsefulStuff

  def test_whatever
    # useful_method available here
  end
end
```

Just define the module in a file and use require to pull it in.  For example, if 'UsefulStuff' is defined in test/support/useful_stuff.rb, you might have require 'support/useful_stuff' in either your individual test file.

UPDATE:

To clarify, in your existing test/test_helper.rb file or in a new test/test_helper.rb file you create, include the following:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("test/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

which will require all files in the test/support subdirectory.

Then, in each of your individual test files just add

```
require 'test_helper'
```

This is exactly analogous to RSpec, where you have a require 'spec_helper' line at the top of each spec file.

Comment: Yeah this is also what I found, but I want to include it in general.. in all test cases..?

Comment: You can use the same method.  Define a test/test_helper.rb and require everything in the test/support directory there.  Then just require the test _helper.rb in all your individual test files - just like RSpec

Comment: I don't understand this question because (1) I just gave you exact instructions and (2) it's just like RSpec

Comment: I dont know how i should write it, that it includes everything in all test cases... If its so easy, then feel free to take my example and change it to the solution :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing I will do is create my own `Test` class inheriting from `Minitest::Test`. This allows me to do any sort of configuration on my base test class and keeping it isolated to my own project<sup>1</sup>.

```
# test_helper.rb
include 'helpers/my_useful_module'
module MyGem
  class Test < Minitest::Test
    include MyUsefulModule
  end
end

# my_test.rb
include 'test_helper'
module MyGem
  MyTest < Test
  end
end
```

<sup>1</sup> This is most likely unneeded, but I like keeping all my gem code isolated.