# Does Phantom.js capture all AJAX?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, phantomjs

I have a backbone app that has a ton of AJAX. (each page load results in 5-6 ajax calls) because I have many views and internal views within those views,

if I run Phantom.js, can I get the final html result?

Final result is what the user sees after all my ajax calls run.

Comment: Why not try for yourself?

Comment: What do you mean with 'the final HTML'? Do you mean something like `document.body.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PhamtonJs is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. When crawling a page, PhatomJs will download all dependants requests such as images, js, css... It will also executes JS and ajax calls. 
However the onLoaded callback is invoked when the page finishes the loading, not when there are no pending requests. So, you have to use a trick for this.

There are two way to solve the problem :

- Wait until "something" effectively changed in you page (an element). The best example is [waitFor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js)
- Wait a few seconds until no requests were received.

Comment: don't really know for node.js. But waitFor.js is a basic example of what you have to do. I'm sure you will be able to use it easily in your case.

Answer (score 11):

Phantom.js is able to run the javascript in your page, so this should work.  There is an [article](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/) describing how to give crawlers nice versions of javascript sites using Phantom.js.

Be sure to give Phantom.js enough time to complete the ajax calls, as this [thread describes](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phantomjs/aac6OVGxG-w).

Comment: there is a dead link here. you shouldn't link to stuff like that

Comment: A webarchive for the dead link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130117045604/http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.active along with waitFor.js script which returns the no of active connection to a server and we need to wait for it to be 0 for all requests to be complete.

More info: [jQuery.active function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access to javascript codes of the website, aside from `waitFor()` way, I think you can make your ajax requests synchronous. It's sometimes simpler and more accurate.