# Phantomjs , ajax content and JS getting inlined

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, requirejs, phantomjs

I have been playing with PhantomJS to generate a static version of some of our application pages that use ajax calls to render sections of the page. The PhantomJS script to get the contents of HTML seems straight forward:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();                                   
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like       Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.70 Safari/537.17';
// I want JS to execute, so that the ajax sections can be loaded
page.settings.javascriptEnabled=true;
page.open('http://<host>/<some-page>/', function (status) {    if (status !== 'success') 
{
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
    console.log(page.content);                                            
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

The issue I am having it, some JS scripts like requirejs and Google Analytics, modify the document by adding relevant JS script and almost inline themselves in the document. for example:
    `<script data-main="main" src="require.js"/>`

Gets converted to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requi    remodule="jquery" src="/media/js/../lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> .....
```

So long story short, I want to use phantomJS to generate a static (HTML) version of the pages that:

1. use ajax requests to populate some sections.
2. Keep the css and JS links as is and avoid them getting inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ravi, please check out @Cybermaxs answer at [Does PhantomJS capture all AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747643/does-phantom-js-capture-all-ajax)

Basically you will have to wait for a particular element to load.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is the route I took.