# Make PhantomJs wait for an Ajax Request before generating a pdf

Tags: phantomjs

Using the example from phantomjs works like a charm

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js?utm_content=bufferda3e0&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer

**However what happens if the url needs to make an Ajax request in order to load it's data? Can I fire a custom event so the pdf is only generated then ?**

(I don't want to guess how much time the request will take and set a timeout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Phantom.js capture all AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747643/does-phantom-js-capture-all-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

The common solution to this problem is to wait for an element that will appear on the page after AJAX request has finished.

Include the `waitFor` function from [this example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) and wait for the first function passed as argument to `waitFor` to return true, then it will run the function passed as the second argument.

```
page.open("https://example.com/ajaxified/", function (status) {
    waitFor(function() {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.querySelectorAll(".report").length > 0;
        });
    }, function() {
       page.render("report.pdf");
       phantom.exit();
    });

});
```