# $.active still shows as "1" when $.Ajax complete event called

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Just as in the Title really. I'm guessing this is by design but would someone mind confirming?

The problem is: I want to trigger another Ajax callback when another one has completed. This rules me out of using the AjaxStop global event as then of course I just end up in an ajax call loop.

I'm just trying to reassure myself that there's no point trying to use the complete event at the mo really. If I know that's a non-starter then I'll have a think about an alternative.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I'm just trying to reassure myself that there's no point trying to use the complete event at the mo really. If I know that's a non-starter then I'll have a think about an alternative.

Comment: Just use the Deferred Object on the ajax calls ?

Comment: That's a new one to me but I'll have a look, thanks. Is it expected that $.active will still be 1 when the complete event fires then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this which confirms:

[jQuery.active function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function)

and posts link to the following source:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L518