# What does $.active means in following jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I'm using following jQuery libraries in my project. Following is the code for adding them:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Now the function which is written by previous developer as follows:

```
function add_rebate_by_product() {
  if($.active > 0) { //or $.active  //What this $.active does   
    request_inprogress();
  } else {
    var manufacturer_id = $("#company_id").val();
    var rebate_no       = $('.well').length;
    var site_url        = $('#site_url').val();

    if ($('.well').length>=0) { 
      rebate_no = rebate_no+1;
    }
      $('.add_new_rebate').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_rebate_by_product.php",
      data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'create_rebate', 'rebate_no':rebate_no, 'manufacturer_id':manufacturer_id},  
      beforeSend: function() { 
        $('.load_img').html("<img src='"+site_url+"img/ajax-loader.gif' class='load' alt='Loading...'>");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if(jQuery.trim(data)=="session_time_out") {
          window.location.href = site_url+'admin/login.php?timeout=1';              
        } else {
          $('.rbt').append(data);
          $('.add_new_rebate').removeAttr('disabled');

          //code for state select control to make functionality workable in newly added rebate block
          $('.states').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            maxHeight: 150
          });
          //code for datepicker control to make functionality workable in newly added rebate block
          $(".date_control").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
          });                   
        }
        $('.load').remove();
      }
    });
//}
}
```

Now can someone please explain what the following files does and what's it's importance?

```
if($.active > 0) { //or $.active        
        request_inprogress();
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $.active is plugin function defined somewhere...

Comment: @user2839497 see this link http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/selenium-wait-for-ajax-the-right-way/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery `$.active` is a function which jQuery uses internally but not mentioned in the official documentation. But there is no problem in using in when we code.

It is a flag to enable global event handlers for `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()`. You can find more details on that [here](http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-jqueryactive-code-works.html) and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function) question.

Here are some code snippets found on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js).

1.

```
// Counter for holding the number of active queries
active: 0,
```

2.

```
// Watch for a new set of requests
if ( fireGlobals && jQuery.active++ === 0 ) {
    jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStart");
}
```

3.

```
// Handle the global AJAX counter
if ( !( --jQuery.active ) ) {
    jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It tests to see if there is an active connection, if there are any ( > 0), it will perform function request_inprogress(), otherwise it will peform the else part of the statement.

It is probably there to prevent the code from processing, while already processing.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery.active

It is described here to test the number of active connections to a server and will evaluate true when the number of connections is zero.

Comment: So, if I remove this code then will the rest of functionality work. Or is it necessary and important part of the whole function code?

Comment: It helps us to give a visual of synchronization  with the other on going Events.
You can remove it only IF "the 'else' part procedure has nothing to with the method request_inprogress();"

Comment: `jQuery.active` will be falsey when there are zero connections, I'd expect. No?