# AngularJs pendant for jQuery.active

Tags: angularjs, selenium, angularjs-http

I'm having timing issues when writing a selenium test for an angular app. There are pending `$http` requests that need finished before the next step gets executed.

If I would use *jQuery*, [I could do the following to check if there are any pending requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function):

```
jQuery.active
```

Does something similar exist for *AngularJS*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equivalent is $http.pendingRequests 
please check the Angualr JS documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: doh, too obvious :/. Thanks for the solution.