# Is there a function to check if there is any running AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any existing JQuery function to check if there is any running AJAX requests.

Comment: http://newsbusters.org/sites/default/files/main_photos/2013/October/No!.jpg

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) to check on the status of your requests.

Comment: Thanks, The code i have is very huge, no way to re-factor it, i am looking for a specific function that give me this information