# How to check if it exists any ajax pending with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do some action:

```
var function some_action() {
    // ...
}
```

But this action requires all the ajax to be finished, so I wrote this way:

```
$(document).one('ajaxStop', some_action);
```

Ok, when all pending ajax request finishes, the function would be fired.

But sometimes when I do it, there is no pending ajax requests, so the `one` event do not fire in these cases!

So I'm finding a way to check if there is any ajax requests that are in progress?

Like:

```
if($.hasAjaxRunning()) {
    $(document).one('ajaxStop', some_action);
} else {
    some_action();
}
```

So that I can make the action guaranteed to be fired.

Comment: Build yourself a switch on ajax start ( in the function that starts it ) and in the done function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply set a global variable to flag that state:

```
// site.js
$(function() {
    window.ajax_loading = false;
    $.hasAjaxRunning = function() {
        return window.ajax_loading;
    };
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        window.ajax_loading = true;
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        window.ajax_loading = false;
    });
});
```

Seeing that, if any ajax request starts, the variable `window.ajax_loading` is set to true. And when all ajax requests was ended, the flag is set to false.

Answer (score 5):

Simple "IF" Statement

```
if ($.active == 0) {
   some_action();
}
```

As a jQuery Function

```
$.hasAjaxRunning = function() {
   return $.active != 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution. More info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148225/1455074