# Javascript to get the number of Ajax request that are ongoing in the current page?

Tags: javascript

Javascript to get the number of Ajax request that are ongoing in the current page? I am using "Jquery.active", which is returning "0" even though there is a ongoing request.

Comment: When do you return that? It is asynchronous.

Comment: how is a property asynchronous @AjAX.? that makes no sense

Comment: I've read in a 8 year old post that `jQuery.active` "will become" `jQuery.ajax.active` - so, I guess the question is, which version of jQuery are you using

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148506/6009304), `jquery.active` became `jquery.ajax.active`. The post is from 2010 so I suspect that has already been done. Also, a comment from 2013 in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function/3148506#comment25407244_3148506) says it is now `$.active`.

Comment: The jQuery version used on SO  — 1.12.4. — has `$.active` and `jQuery.active`. It is — not — `jQuery.ajax.active`. It is important to call at the right moment @JaromandaX. Because the whole `AJAX` thing is asynchronous.

Comment: yes, but the value of `jQuery.active` is not *asynchronous*

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX, The value i.e returned when I execute the command jQuery.active is not asynchronous.

Comment: I need the command/JS code that returns the counts or the "true" or "false" if there are any AJAX calls are happening at the time when I execute this command/JS in the browser.
Can You Please help me in getting it. I am new to JavaScript world

Comment: Your command is nearly right. Do you know about the `console`? In Chrome it is right click and `Inspect`. Then `console`. There you can output from your JS code like `console.log('lineNumberInCode', jQuery.active)`. Have joy.