# Ajax call to return a task status? ( in progress OR finished)

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I have a html table with tasks and the last column is called "status". I need to do a simple thing, to track the status of each task with the usual way of an animating gif icon if its in progress or an ok check if its done.

I have done this in the past by calling a php script with $.ajax that it was refreshing itself every 1 minute. The script was a PHP script with one query that checked a boolean column. This approach was ok, but even then I knew that this was most probably the dumbest way to do something like this.

I am looking for a more robust way to do this and while I was searching I found this snippet

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#divToRefresh').load('/path/to/your/php/file/userCount.php');
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds.
});
</script>
```

Something like this could work but how do I stop this refresh if the task was actually finished? Something like "Gaurav Sharma" answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872287/ajax-request-in-progress-jquery) is the way to go?

I am a newbie in Jquery so I would really love to know how would you do something like this, seems a common task so I hesitate to re-invent the wheel by writing 2 pages of code for something that can be done with 5 lines :-)

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're using something as old as jQuery 1.4.2?

Comment: I am not using it. I found it like this, I will definitely use the latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#divToRefresh').load('/path/to/your/php/file/userCount.php');
    if(somecondition){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds.
```

calling `clearInterval(interval)` stops the repetition.

Comment: the 'somecondition' can look in the DOM? For example it can be something like if($('#divtorefresh').text=='loading') {clearInterval(interval);} So I guess I am asking this, each time it refreshes the div it runs the if statement?

Comment: `somecondition can` be anything, so yes, you can use DOM based conditions. Also, yes, after refreshing the div it runs the check, but you can put this check anywhere in your script. The basic premise is that calling clearInterval with the original interval ID will stop it.

Comment: I'll try this out. I have concerns how the code will look like if I have 10 tasks in the table tha runs this check.

Comment: I am trying this http://paste.laravel.com/8Dh but I got the error = "TypeError: $(".checkcampstatus").setInterval is not a function"

Comment: Is jQuery included? Also, is an element with class checkcampstatus in the markup? Your link just seems to contain a fragment of js.

Comment: Additionally, setInterval is not a jQuery method. It is a method of the window.

Comment: The problem was the chaining. Obviously setInterval can't be chained.

Comment: @GeorgeD. so is it fixed now?

Comment: No. I'll keep trying, nothing is working as it should be so I'll make a restart and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement some code like this

```
var interval = null; // has to be global in this example

// [...] your code

interval = setInterval(function(...));

// [...] your code
```

if your script completes just call `clearInterval(interval)` from anywhere