# How to report progress of asynchronous server task in realtime and read the progress with client side JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Here's a use case:

- I'm using ASP .NET Web Forms 3.5 & jQuery
- On the web page, I initialize a javascript request to the server (eg. DoAsyncTask.aspx)
- On the server I take advantage of **RegisterAsyncTask**. Inside registered asynchronous task, I write info about the progress directly to Response output stream, like this:

```
// Called when task starts in order no to buffer the output 
Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Writing single progress message looks like this (please comment on it as well, as it works almost as I want):

```
Response.Write(message + Environment.NewLine);    
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

It works nice (almost) when I initialize request to DoAsyncTask.aspx from browser (I can see single line messages comming from the server). (I works almost nice because sometimes single lines I get from the server are truncated - propably browser buffering???)

But I don't know how to do it with client side & jQuery. What I would like to do on client side, is to display flushed messages in some kind of element (like ) as they come from the server. How can I do it?

Comment: I was searching for the same, I found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099484/ajax-call-to-return-a-task-status-in-progress-or-finished