# Avoiding two simultaneous ajax calls with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax request in progress jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872287/ajax-request-in-progress-jquery)

what I try to achieve is something like :

```
var calling = {};
if(!calling[resourceId]){
    $.ajax(...);
    calling[resourceId] = true;
}
```

Obviously, I want to avoid making two calls for the same resource at the same time. But I find it ugly to use a global variable across my scripts for this. I would like to know if you knew a nice way to handle this directly with jQuery ?

The best solution that I can think of is a monkey patch on jQuery.ajax to provide it with some "resourceId" parameter, and before any call the jQuery.ajax() function itself would check if a call is already being made with that "resourceId". I could not find such an option in the $.ajax documentation and I wonder why !?

Thank you.

**UPDATE: I found exactly what I was looking for on in jQuery's Prefilters option, on the "Extending Ajax" documentation page. : http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/**

Thanks for tips people :)

Comment: You can use the same concept without having to make your variables attached to `window`.  I usually wrap up this kind of communication in a class.

Comment: If its a get query then in normal settings it is cached by browser. You can use it to ur advantage.

Comment: @Brad: on window or a custom class, I still find it messy, I feel it should be handled by $.ajax itself. Rory : maybe duplicate, but the answer there was not satisfying. Subirkumarsao: when the query is being made, it is not cached yet

Comment: Maybe [jQuery.whenSync() Plugin For Chaining Asynchronous Callbacks Using Deferred Objects](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm) might be useful.

Comment: @Evan, Why should it be handled by jQuery?  Suppose I want to fire off a few requests at once without waiting.  That's the whole point of such methods being asynchronous.  The cool thing with this is you can make a wrapper class to do what you want, if you wish.

Comment: if you find what you are looking for post it and mark it as an answer dont edit your question.

Comment: I re-read the other topic and my question is actually NOT a duplicate. I was talking about two simultaneous requests for a SAME resource, not two different requests (the code I gave may have mislead you I admit). Otherwise, I agree with @Brad that it would not make much sense. Can someone please reopen the question so I can post the code I came up with ? I have not seen my solution anywhere else and I think it might help a bunch of people.